# Spring / Stomp / RabbitMQ - convertAndSendToUser() Issues

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, stomp

I developed a server & client in Spring which uses Web Sockets via STOMP, all of which works perfectly using the SimpleBroker:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker( MessageBrokerRegistry pConfig ) 
{
    pConfig.enableSimpleBroker( "/queue", "/topic" );
```

I am now trying to switch over to use RabbitMQ as the message broker:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker( MessageBrokerRegistry pConfig ) 
{
    pConfig.enableStompBrokerRelay( "/queue", "/topic" );
```

I have added the appropriate dependencies to the POM, installed RabbitMQ by following the instructions on their website & the applications seem to run correctly.

However, whenever the server sends a message direct to a specific user:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate   theTemplate; 

theTemplate.convertAndSendToUser( pHeaderAccessor.getUser().getName(), "/queue/device", lResponse );
```

I see the following output in the log:

```
25-01-2018 15:52:19.782 | ERROR      | reactor-tcp-io-1               | aging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler$StompConnectionHandler | 652   | Received ERROR {message=[Invalid destination], content-type=[text/plain], version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[62]} session=_system_ text/plain payload='/**USERNAME**/queue/device' is not a valid exchange destination
```

From reading the RabbitMQ / STOMP page, I can see that there is a limited number of destination types of which '/user' is not one of them, which I'm guessing is why the error is being generated.

What is the correct way to send a message to a user now that I am using RabbitMQ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some details as to the exchange/queue bindings on RabbitMQ? It's not really clear what is meant by "trying to send directly to a user" in terms of the objects that RabbitMQ understands.

Comment: I have done absolutely *nothing* with RabbitMQ, other than install it via the supplied instructions, enable the STOMP plugin & run it. There is nothing in the documentation that implies I have to do anything else to get it up & running.

Comment: I would say you need to do a little more digging to get to the heart of the issue. I'm pretty good at understanding RabbitMQ, but I don't really know what your code is trying to do via STOMP, and I suspect it will be hard for anyone else as well.